# Set a UIImageView's Image based on Binary Data

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an image I'm trying to load from a web service. I've tested the data I got from the web service by adding `data:image/gif;base64,` before it and entering it as a URL in Chrome and the image loaded perfectly.

In my iOS app, I tried `profilePic.image = UIImage.init(data: picData.data(using: .utf8)!)` where `picData` is a string with the contents I tested above, however nothing loaded.

I get the feeling what I did wrong is somewhere in `picData.data(using: .utf8)!)` but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

In case it helps, here's the binary data I'm working with: https://pastebin.com/xiWHaPB6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode Strings **not** arbitrary 8 bit data!

Your if the mime type you've shown is accurate, the data is a Base64 encoded string.  The first thing you want to do is convert that string to an unencoded, binary form.  Then try creating your UIImage from that:

```
let unencodedData = Data(base64Encoded: picData)
let image = UIImage(data: unencodedData)
```